# Finding a string in a line in a file and displaying it in unix

Tags: unix, command

I have a file which has three lines as follows;

```
/abdf/rewisf/dkjrtr/ser/co.c  -o /abdf/rewisf/dkjrtr/wrewr.o
/erwrw/srejr/eroi -I/serwr/erw/reti/ -o /erwer/tryps/trtwre.o
/serer/rtppqwe/rtr -lm -Isejr/ekrlafk -o ekr/eirw/qwpog/gset.o
```

I need a unix command which displays only the file which ends with ".o" extension with the **full pathname** in the above line. 
For example, in the above case, my requirement should display following in each line;

```
/abdf/rewisf/dkjrtr/wrewr.o
/erwer/tryps/trtwre.o
/ekr/eirw/qwpog/gset.o
```

Please help. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other than sed and awk specifying lines and columns, give me a unix command whose logic should be like, it should search for -o in the file and print the immediate whole file name with path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -n 's/^.*\( .*\.o\).*$/\1/gp' test.txt
```

Will only find one instance of the pattern! If you have a version of grep which accepts -o as an option, you can use this:

```
egrep -o ' .*.o' test.txt
```

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for the suggestion. My requirement is, the command should search for -o in the file and print/display only the immediate filename with path(eg:/ekr/eirw/qwpog/gset.o). Kindly help, if you have any idea.

Comment: `sed -n 's/.*-o \(.*\.o\)/\1/gp' test.txt` works for me

Comment: It worked for me too. Thanks a lot for your timely help Josh.